# Building a loop

Tags: java, class

I built a running calculator with a java class. I have hit a snag. I have the complete calculator built and coded on Microsoft Word (the functions, etc.).

I need to add onto it, with a loop; where I left off runs perfect. Now I need to continue on it and every time I make an entry it says, "do not place this here". If this is so, how far do I go down or what do I need to add onto the calculator?

Please advise if I am asking this right or not.

Here is some of the calculator:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

      //Declaring and initializing the variables
      double principle = 200000.0;
      double interestRate = 0.0575;
      int term = 360;

      DecimalFormat decimalPlaces=new DecimalFormat("0.00");

      // Calculating the monthly payment: M = P [ i(1 + i)n ] / [ (1 +  i)n - 1]
      double monthlyRate = (interestRate/12);
      double t = Math.pow((1 + monthlyRate),term);
      double payment = (principle * monthlyRate * t) / (t-1);

      //Display the results on computer screen
      System.out.println("The monthly payment for a mortgage of 200000 is $" + 
          decimalPlaces.format(payment));
```

This is what I am trying to add:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "math.h"

using namespace std;

double calcPayment(double principle, double rate, double term) {
```

Comment: "built on Microsoft word" with Java...?

Comment: Unfortunately, the way you've asked this question is very unclear. Remember that you need to assume we know nothing about how your program is set up. Please edit your question to be as clear and detailed as possible, and include code samples if applicable. Also, work on correct punctuation and reducing your run-on sentences.

Comment: Take a breath. You're really not making your problem clear. Are you writing Java code or not? How does Word come into this? Why do you think you need a loop? What do you mean by "everytime I make an entry It says do not place this here"? And as Dave says: show some code.

Comment: yes I put all the codes on java on microsoft word then took and placed them on the new netbean 6.9.1 java class and it works but I am snagged. Do I need to build a loop and if so where do i place it.

Comment: ok, so your Java class was given to you as a Word document and you copy-pasted it into Netbeans?

Comment: @buddy what is your program trying to do? what does your code look like so far? What loop are you trying to build, and why do you need it?

Comment: why you want to build a loop? why you need this?

Comment: Ok, so I'm assuming that you need some sort of input loop? That is, the user keeps entering data and you calculate the interest, until they decide to exit?

Comment: Microsoft word + C++ + java? :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should change in your algorithm terms because this should be in years not days. Regarding to [Mortgage Payment Calculator](http://www.snippetit.com/2009/07/java-mortgage-payment-calculator/) your method to calculate should looks like this:

```
public static double calculateMonthlyPayment(double principle, double rate, int termsInYears) {
    double mRate = rate / 12 / 100;
    int months = termsInYears * 12;
    double pow = Math.pow((1 + mRate), months);

    return (1.0 - 1.0 / (1 - pow)) * mRate * principle;
}   

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // Declaring and initializing the variables
    double principle = 200000.0;
    double interestRate = 0.0575;
    int terms = 12;

    DecimalFormat decimalPlaces = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    System.out.println("The monthly payment for a mortgage of 200000 is $"
            + decimalPlaces.format(calculateMonthlyPayment(principle, interestRate, terms)));
}
```

But really I'm guessing if this is what you want - I don't know why you want use loop

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "math.h"

using namespace std;
```

That's not java. It looks like you copied some c++ code and tried to add it to your java class.